# How to do Sequential (Online Learning) One Hot Encoding in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, sequential, one-hot-encoding

I have a database that is too large to enter into memory, thus I am forced to load it in sequentially. The original dataset has categorical variables with 15 unique values, but in each splice I take I usually only get 10-11 unique values and this is causing me a problem when one-hot-encoding my pandas dataframe.

---

What I am looking for is a function that can do this:

```
1) First go through my database sequentially logging all unique
values

2) Then one-hot-encoding based on that
```

Comment: [This](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/25686/54046) is your answer.